# Import datetime from txt

Tags: matlab

I am trying to read a table with timeseries data.

The first column defines the date/time in the format 01.01.1998 00:00.

I read the table by:

```
T = readtable('Abflussdaten.txt','DatetimeType','text');
```

Then I tried to convert the first column to datetime:

```
D = T.Datum;
date = datetime(D,'InputFormat','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm')
```

This gives me: *Error using datetime (line 616)
Unable to parse date/time text using the format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'*.

This is how the table looks like:

```
Datum;Q_Kempten;Q_Sonthofen
01.01.1998 00:00;27.010;9.6700
01.01.1998 01:00;26.810;9.6600
01.01.1998 02:00;26.610;9.6500
```

What am I doing wrong? I think it is related to the date format, but it seems to be correct.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

- Your date is in the wrong order (`yyyy MM dd` instead of `dd MM yyyy`).
- You are using the wrong separator (`-` instead of `.`).

Use:

```
date = datetime(D,'InputFormat','dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm')
```

Comment: Oh god, your right! However, this brings me to the next issue: All datetime values are shown as NaT...

Comment: Can you share what your table looks like in your question?

Comment: Can't reproduce `T = readtable('test.txt','DatetimeType','text');D = T.Datum;date = datetime(D,'InputFormat','dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm')`

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you on?

Answer (score 0):

Your date format seems wrong.
Try changing your date format from `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` to `dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm`.